# Tamil poetess Avai said that Lord Shiva is the Supreme god of all?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, shiva, krishna

In a poetic song Avaiyar said that lord Bharama was born from Lord Vishnu's navel where Lord Vishnu born from ocean and where ocean adapted into saga Gurumoni's vessel and he born from kalasam and the length of kalasha is same as Adisesa's one head and he adapts in Lord Parvathi's small ring and she is always under Lord Shiva. So Lord Shiva is the supreme of all gods ! 
Upto my knowledge Avai never praise Lord Vishnu who is considered to be same as Lord Shiva. Why? Is Lord Shiva and Vishnu are same ? If so why Avai never say any thing about Lord vishnu ?

Comment: The continuation is Lord Shiva is always in his devotee's heart so the devotee is Supreme.

Comment: Besides what is your question?

Comment: What is your question? Shaivaites consider Shiva as supreme and Vaishnavites consider Vishnu as supreme. He is Brahman by common name. I'm closing your question as unclear.

Comment: @Surya The OP only wanted to share information and not ask question. New users don't know that "Ask a question" can/should only be used to ask question. For them, it is the way to share their knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Many siva devotees claim that lord siva is supreme. this is simply out of their attachment to lord siva. there is no truth to it. the scriptural evidence is

1. in siva purana, parvati asks lord siva - which is the best worship?

lord siva answers - out of all worships, worshipping vishnu is the supreme.

2. lord siva himself will be chanting the "taraka mantra" which is "sri rama rama rama"
3. Lord vishnu creates brahma from His navel, lord brahma creates lord siva from his eyebrows when he was angry. because lord siva was born from anger of brahma, he is called rudra. so, siva is a created being but no one created vishnu. He is the original creator. creator and created can not be equal